# running jboss-el with tomcat 6 and jsp2.1

Tags: jsp, jsf, jboss, tomcat6

I need to send parameters in my EL Expression.

So i put jboss-el jar.

as well, I added the tag:

```
<context-param>     
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
<param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

in my web.xml of the project.

But it seems to me that it stil uses the old expression factory!

how can i handle it?

Comment: The parameter name suggests that you're using MyFaces JSF implementation. Is this true? Which JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: Any interesting errors/warnings/infos in server's startup logs?

Comment: nothing! this is what interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El expression doesn't work with JSP2.1 in tomcat 6.
I had to switch to facelet

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Tomcat 7.x as it implements JSP 2.2

see also [Which version to use](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: Sometimes you're restricted by business desicions as to which server to use. Also, at the time of writing this question, Tomcat 7 was still in beta stage.

Comment: that's true (actually at my company i'm stuck with glassfish v2.2 :), it was more a hint for other people who have the same problem.